# Is Task-based programming acceptable in an ASP.Net page or Async page is the preferred approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using the following Task based programming (TPL) in a page that is not an Async page.

My question is: **Is it ok to use TPL (i.e. Task Parallel Library) for creating multi-threaded calls in an ASP.Net page, or one must always use the inbuilt Async page feature for multi-threading in an ASP.Net page?** So far the TPL approach hasn't created any problems, but just wanted to be sure in case I missed some important point/hidden risks with using TPL in an ASP.Net page.

```
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Method1(); 
                        success4 = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e4)
                    {
                        success4 = false;
                        ex = e4.ToString();
                    }
                }),
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Method2();
                        success5 = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e5)
                    {
                        success5 = false;
                        ex = e5.ToString();
                    }
                }),
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Method3();
                        success6 = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e6)
                    {
                        success6 = false;
                        ex = e6.ToString();
                    }
                })
            };
   Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As pointed out in the answer, using TPL in ASP.Net would limit scalability of the ASP.Net app, since each task uses a thread from ASP.Net thread pool, and at the same time keeps the original thread of the page in a blocked state.
I am now thinking about using TPL when calling the method in an Async page as in code below, to take advantage of more powerful processing that parallelism brings. But I will investigate this further to see whether in a real situation, TPL will make it better or worse for the async method.

```
private void DoTask4(object[] paras)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
               try
               {
                   Method4( paras);
               }
               catch (Exception e4)
               {
                   success4 = false;
                   //log the exception
               }
           });
    }

    IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation4(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        task4 = new AsyncTaskDelegate(DoTask4);
        IAsyncResult result = task4.BeginInvoke(state as object[], cb, "task4");
        return result;
    }

    void EndAsyncOperation4(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        task4.EndInvoke(ar);
        if (success4 == null)
        {
            success4 = true;
        }
    }

    void TimeoutAsyncOperation4(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        success4 = false;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Finally, as pointed out in the answer, even using TPL with Async page method would also cause a thread from thread pool to get used, which again means our ASP.Net scalability will be an issue.
So, its best not to use TPL inside an Async page.

Comment: it should be fine, are you using straight asp.net or mvc?

Comment: Well, `Task.WaitAll` is far from ideal. You're probably causing at least one thread to be stuck waiting in that call rather than accomplishing any useful work (assuming all of the tasks have actually started running on other threads by the time the call is made).

Comment: @NedStoyanov, I am using ASP.NET WebForms and not MVC.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, If I comment out the Task.WaitAll code, will the page eventually wait before sending the response to browser AND where can I track succes/failure of each thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach may seriously hurt the server scalability, because it uses extra theads and blocks the request thread. Suppose `Method1..3` are responsible for some IO-bound work. If you can't use async ASP.NET controllers, you still can start an async IO-bound operation with `AsyncManager` (e.g., like [this](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/aspnet-mvc-asynccontroller-helper.html)) or with [`PageAsyncTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx) (for classic ASP.NET) and avoid blocking.

If however you need to do some CPU-bound work (as opposed to IO-bound work), just do it on the same request thread, step by step, rather than in parallel. Otherwise, each `Task.Factory.StartNew` may be putting another incoming HTTP request on hold, depending on the server load. Because you probably want to serve as many concurrent HTTP requests as possible, you should avoid parallelizing CPU-bound work.

That said, your code might be fine for an intranet web app with low number of concurrent HTTP requests. You could do so if you want to speed up the response delivery for an individual request.

Comment: Great. So using async page where Async= 'true' for ASP.Net page is the way to go for scalability. Since Task.Factory would pick up a thread from ASP.Net thread pool without giving up the original page thread, then yes that would limit scalability in a high traffic scenario. Thanks for clearing that. If I use Parallel.Invoke when calling the async method in an Async page, you think that would help since the async method will then use multiple processors as opposed to just one processor?

Comment: @Sunil, I think using `Parallel.Invoke` would have the same effect as it uses thread pool too (possibly, it does that in a more clever way, depending on the number of actual CPU cores). Moreover, `Parallel.Invoke` blocks the calling thread, too.

Comment: Ok. So TPL with Async page method is not a good idea. Thanks again for clearing that up.

Comment: @Sunil, are you doing CPU intensive job inside `Method1..3`? Or is it IO/network/database related?

Comment: Its all database related using Entity Framework 4.0.

Comment: @Sunil, unlike EF6, EF4 doesn't have asynchronous API. So just call it on the request thread as needed, without using `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in my code now. Appreciate all your help with the detailed explanations.